# Unable to get backup due to GPG error

Tags: updates, backup, encryption, gnupg

I involuntarily erased all data from my hard drive, but I have a new backup on an external drive.
Trying to restore I get:

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:  
===== Begin GnuPG log =====  
gpg: AES256 encrypted data  
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase  
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key  
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I had to reinstall Ubuntu as well - is that the problem? How do I get my files back?
Resolved - I changed the stored password in the pw and keys app to misspelled versions and former passwords and retried the restore - one of them was it!

Comment: How did you create the backup? Is it on an encrypted drive?

Comment: On an external USB drive - without encyption - sorry, wrong. I added a password, but it does not work with it
The Ubuntu update was from the 18 lts to 20 lts - as I had to redo averything anyway

Comment: I meant with what software? Did you use any particular application for the backup? And what do you do to restore when you get that message?

Comment: soryy - deja up - and i started deja up on the new system, chose the folders whre to find the backup and to put it

Comment: That's what I expected. Without knowing how Deja Dup works exactly, I suspect you chose an encrypted backup, which encrypted the files using GPG with your user keyring, and now your new user cannot decrypt the files. Did it ask you to enter a password when restoring?

Comment: [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/PassphraseProblems2019) might also help...

Comment: Yes it asked - I used the one I had before - maybe I misspelled it. Hm. Trying to reset on the passords and keys app?

Comment: I would have a look at Passwords and Keys and see if there is an entry for "Backup Encryption Password" like it says in the link I gave above, and see what password it contains. If not, and you're absolutely sure you know the right password, I would try what they suggest under "How to confirm the issue" to see if it is actually a bug with the software.

Comment: Resolved! I tried out some misspelled pw and former - and got it! phew.